# xhtml2pdf keep-with-previous.within-page

Tags: html, css, django, pdf-generation, xhtml2pdf

I'm using the xhtml2pdf library in Django 3.x.
I don't know how to make the style work in the template, and still transfer text that is too long to the next page, but only its further part.
I'm currently using this code snippet, the rest of the text is moved to the next page, but the styles don't work:

```
<xsl:attribute name="keep-with-previous.within-page">
<tr>
    <th class="col332">
        {{ instance.myvar|linebreaks }}
    </th>
</tr>
</xsl:attribute>
```